# JavaFX application does not accept touch inputs

Tags: touchscreen, java, desktop, javafx

I am trying to run a javaFX application on a raspberry pi 3b+ with a 7" 1024x600 touchscreen by Lebula. When I plug a mouse in, the application works as normal, but, when I try to use the touchscreen, it does not work. The touch screen does work on the regular desktop, however. I am using mouse events in the javaFX code instead of touch events, but I don't think that is the problem. How can I make the javaFX application accept input from the touchscreen?

Comment: you are not using touch events and you do not think that is the problem? ... have you ran a test to be sure?

Comment: I saw that a mouse event also works with touch, but that is a good idea, I will try it.

Comment: I just tried and it still doesn't work. @jsotola

Comment: Do you know which events your touchscreen produces? Is it key press/release, or button clicks?

Comment: @Dimitry Grigoryev     How do I figure that out?

Comment: Comments stream from Higgin's deleted answer has been moved to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105805/discussion-on-answer-by-higgins-javafx-application-does-not-accept-touch-inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a basic problem with the support of the touchscreen under "Raspbian buster". My JavaFX application did not respond to the touch events and I thought the problem was with the application until I tested touch screen support on existing applications. Some widgets respond to touch, but some do not. The pulldowns will be e.g. is displayed, but the items it contains do not react to touch. I have the "official 7 inch touchscreen". 
Install Raspbian strech and test with it.